# Started making my app, now need story boards

Tags: iphone, xcode

So istarted making my first app and it's just a single view application but now i've realised it might be useful to have the story board feature enabled (now that I know what i can do with it). I didn't tick it when I started.

Is it too late to enable it? What's the easiest way to move my app into a storyboard enabled file?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not too late

Right click on your code and choose `New File` -> under  `IOS` -> `User Interface`-> `Storyboard` -> Iphone -> Save As `Storyboard`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now find your Info.plist (it should be in your resources or supported files) right click and choose add row find `Main storyboard file base name`  on value `Storyboard`

[image]

In your app didfinishlaunchingwithoptions return yes

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

        return YES;

}
```

Now go to your storyboard and add Uiviewcontrollers, navigation controllers etc...

Make sure your first uiviewcontroller is set to initial view  controller

[image]

Comment: What do you mean choose story board, UIViewcontrollers etc? I'm with you up to that point.

Comment: No when you add new file, choose user interface,under user interface you will see Storyboard... I will add some pictures

Comment: Make sure in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method that you remove any configurations with your window. If you do not this can cause you to have a blank screen. It is best if you just initialize the window and let storyboard handle the rest.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to that method, will I be alright just leaving it as it is? Once I copy the contents of my xib into the story board, can I just delete it?

Comment: you should be able to copy paste your contents of xib to a uiviewcontroller in storyboard

Comment: Nice one Space Dust, i'll give that a go this evening. I've got all tjhis other code in my didFinishLaunchingwithOptions method. It was all there already, shall I keep that? self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[CGViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CGViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

Comment: Can I copy and paste my view from my xib into the storyboard and make it the initial view controller?

Comment: you need to delete it only `return yes;` needs to stay there

Comment: I am not sure if you can directly copy past your whole Xib, what I meant by copy paste is your design and buttons, I strongly suggest you to just create your a new uiview  controller and add your content one by one