# How to link Storyboard and Class in Empty app

Tags: iphone, xcode, class, storyboard

fellows!

I request you help for my doubt below:

1. I started an Empty Application in order to use the Core Data.
2. After, I inserted a UIViewController class without XIB called MainView.m and MainView.H.
3. And, I inserted an Storyboard.
4. So, I tried to link MainView and the Storyboard using the menu on the right side of the screen, but the MainView didn´t appear in the field "Class".

Does anybody know why?

Already, I thank

Comment: try to force and write MainView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a ViewController in the storyboard, then only go in the right menu in the Custom Class and select the name of your class

I can't post images but here is one

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxuPc.png]

Comment: Thanks a lot, everybody! I found my solution when I read jdiego's  suggestion. I had a Navigation Controller in my Storyboard. Because of that the mainView.h didn't appear in the field "Custom Class". When I deleted the Navigation Controller and inserted the UIViewController, everything was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your plist and your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

See the answer:

[Started making my app, now need story boards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044100/started-making-my-app-now-need-story-boards/14044174#14044174)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you start with the Master-Detail Application template instead (with storyboard and Core Data). It works right out of the box, and even if you don't end up using a master-detail architecture, it has the storyboard and *lots* of templated boilerplate code for Core Data that you'll be able to use later on with very little modification.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your storyboard
Drag and Drop a ViewController onto the storyboard
Click on the yellow icon of the view controller
Display Utilities area
Display the inspector in utilities hover over icons in utilities to find it
Find the class you created under custom class

Completed