# Xcode: Can you add a Storyboard midway through development

Tags: ios, storyboard

I started developing an application, adding and coding up view controllers manually. I was wondering whether it was possible to add a storyboard after development has started? The reason I ask is that if I create a blank storyboard project with one or more linked view controllers, I do not see any of the traditional view switching code. I assume that the storyboards are doing something clever behind the scenes which I cannot see.

So if I already have two view controllers and then add a storyboard, will I damage any of the code I have already written for example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044100/started-making-my-app-now-need-story-boards/14044174#14044174

Answer (score 1):

No, adding the storyboard won't damage any code. You can (I believe) copy the nibs one by one into your storyboard.

There are some things to be aware of, though:

1. You don't use `initWithNib` anymore, you use `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]`
2. Storyboards are much better, and may lead to increased productivity *.

<sub><sub>* Your mileage may vary.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thanks for this, I have manage to copy my nib contents into my view controllers in the storyboard. You need to make sure that the View controller in the storyboard has the same class name as the .h and .m files, and once done you can get rid of the XIB. Of course if you have any references to this file, or InitWithNib then you need to fix these!